# Rails 4 - Devise :return_to previous url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

In Rails 4.2.4, I am using the Devise gem (3.5.6, 3.5.2, 3.2.4), and trying to make it work for a particular scenario.

When a user tries to access the `user_profile_url(:anchor=>'section1')` page from an email, it asks him to login; after login, it leads to `users_home_path`.  If he is already logged in, then it redirects to `user_profile_url` page(#section1).

I want to redirect to `user_profile_url(:anchor=>'section1')` as soon as the session is created (clicked from email link)?  I have tried to fix it by modifying `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` method, but it is not working.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:return_to] || users_home_path
end
```

In html views,

```
<div id="unsubscribe">
...
</div>
```

How can I get this redirect to work?

Comment: did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write code for session[:return_to] like the below the snippet

```
def store_location
  # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
  return unless request.get? 
  if (request.path != "/users/sign_in" &&
      request.path != "/users/sign_up" &&
      request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
      request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
      request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
      request.path != "/users/sign_out" &&
      !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
  end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Comment: `session[:return_to] || users_home_path` is working fine but the issue is with the `:anchor`. Its not leading to 'section1' in the same page.